# Is there a way to figure out a modem/router web IP address?

Tags: debian, ip, router, modem

I bought a Modem/Router d-link dsl-2750u couple of years back. I changed the web IP Address and now I don't remember what IP Address did I put in its place. Is there a way to figure out at what IP Address the web page is ?

I am able to ping the modem/router via ping and know for sure it has busybox (some version). Is it possible to figure out more ?

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and give us more detail. Precisely please.

Comment: Your best be might be to just do a factory reset. There should be a small button on the back you can press and hold down with a pin.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear what you want, but here goes:

`ping` usually shows what ip it's using. That might be the address on your LAN side of the router, but that is most likely what you need.

If you're looking for the address on the WAN side, you can try visiting sites like http://whatismyip.com, but if your ISP uses CGN (Carrier Grade NAT) the reported IP will not be configured on your router. I don't know any simple ways to get the IP on the WAN side of our router in such as setup, but I also fail to see the use.

Answer (score 0):

Actually my modem/router is on 192.168.1.1 . I just needed to un-plug the telephone cable and I was able to access the homepage of the router/modem.